# How to call parent method from child in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have to generate tabs by iterating a object.

Parent class is `TabsList` & child class is `TabsListItems`. Data is flowing form parent to child as props. Now in child class there is a `<li>` element (which is baisclly tab).
`OnClick` of it `selectTab` method should be called which is there in actiotn.js
But my `matchDispatchToProps(dispatch )` method is in the parent.

How can i invoke method which is bind in parent class?

I am passing a object as props to child class

#### parent component

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {connect} from 'react-redux';
    import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
    import {selectTab} from '../actions/index';
    import PlanTabsList from './PlanTabsList';

    class TabList extends React.Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

      }

      createTabItems(){   
        return this.props.tabList.map((item, i) => {
          return (
                  <PlanTabsList key={i} tabList={item} /> 
            )
        });
      }

      render() {        
        return (
          <div id="layout-header" className="layout-header">
            <div id="header" className="header">
               <ul className="tabs tabs--horizontal">

                  {this.createTabItems()}

                </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    };


    function mapStateToProps(state){      
      return {
        tabList: state.tabList,
        activeTab: state.activeTab      
      }
    }

    function matchDispatchToProps(dispatch){
      return bindActionCreators({selectTab: selectTab}, dispatch);
    }    
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, matchDispatchToProps)(TabList);
```

#### child component

```
    import React from 'react'; 
    class  TabsListItems extends React.Component {

      constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props.tabList)
      }


      render() {

        return (
          <li onClick={() => this.props.selectTab(this.props.tabList)}
              role="presentation" className={"tab  " }>
              <a href="#"> 
                <div className="tab__label">   
                  <div className="tab__label__value">{this.props.tabList.name}</div>
                </div>
              </a>
          </li>        
        );
      }
    };      
    export default TabsListItems;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to invoke a function in parent component from deeply nested child component using redux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091627/how-to-invoke-a-function-in-parent-component-from-deeply-nested-child-component)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get callback from child to parent class in react-redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224883/how-to-get-callback-from-child-to-parent-class-in-react-redux)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I already answered in your duplicate question: [how to get callback from child to parent class in react-redux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224883/how-to-get-callback-from-child-to-parent-class-in-react-redux)

Anyway, I copy it here, too.

You should pass a function to the child component via props.

As the action has a parameter to select the correct tab, you can use a function returning a function:

```js
createTabItems() {    
    return this.props.tabList.map((item, i) => {
        return (
            <TabsListItem key={i} tabList={item} onSelect={() => this.onSelect(i).bind(this)} /> 
        );
    });
}
```

In this way your child component calls your method `onSelect` passing the correct parameter.

In your `onSelect` method on the parent (container) component you will then dispatch your action:

```
onSelect(i) {
  this.props.selectTab(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Matteo Frana